# Cannot access last state of db in fixed thread pool

Tags: java, threadpool

In my Spring project, I am using ExecutorService. Before submission of executor, I save an entity but cannot reach it in runnable task. Here is my code:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
    ...
    public void myMethod(){
          MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
          ... //set values
          myRepository.save(myEntity);
          ExecutorService myExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
          myExecutorService.submit(() -> {
              ...
              MyEntity myEntity2 = myRepository.findByName(name);
              ...
          });
    }
}
```

in 'MyEntity myEntity2 = myRepository.findByName(name);' line, does not throw any error, does not return null and does not execute after this line. I think JPA considers that they are in different session and becuase of that, their state is different. Is there a way to fix that?

EDIT: In development environment, I use H2 database. This problem does not happen when H2 is used.